# Virtual Host SSL and nonSSL with Proxy

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-proxy, mod-ssl

I have 1 nonSSL server and many SSL with Proxy in Apache.

Configuration SSL server:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName test.com
        ServerAdmin test@test.com
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/...
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/...
        SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/...

        ProxyRequests off
        SSLProxyEngine on

        ProxyPass / https://localhost:10000/
        ProxyPassReverse / https://localhost:10000/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName test.com
        ServerAdmin test@test.com
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}$1 [R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

Configuration nonSSL server:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName test.test.com
        ServerAdmin test@test.com
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        ProxyRequests off

        ProxyPass / http://localhost:8101/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8101/
</VirtualHost>
```

When I follow to SSL Server - all ok. When I follow nonSSL server Chrome show me SSL server.

What would be problem?

Comment: Do you have HSTS headers active?

Comment: @GeraldSchneider In Apache - I don't set on this setting, if it not default setting. I see stange behaviour my Firefox either. When I follow `http://test.test.com` - all ok, to open nonSSL site. But when I do `https://test.test.com` I see `test.com`, but `https://test.test.com` don't have SSL. Why? It's a magic. I don't understand anything.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand with your comment (which could be added to the main question) the expected behaviour is :
When you hit https://test.test.com => be redirected to http://test.test.com and don't stay on test.com.
It looks like test.com is the defaut and this should be normal when you hit "https://" scheme to go through *:443 vhost.
If this assumption is right, then you should tell in the https (*:443) section : "hey, just go back to http://" like this

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test\.test\.com [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://test.test.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Yes, it's my default site (first site in confing) - `https://test.com`. As I undestand you mean if I have only site `http://test.test.com` and I follow to `https://test.test.com` then is it normal to show my default site? I expect some error - this's ok behavior for me.

Comment: Yes the default behaviour is to show something not throwing an error. I mean with your rewrite config you will always be redirected if you try to reach the "http vhost"